# How can I do video classification while taking into account the temporal dependencies of the frames?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request, video-classification, action-recognition

I need to solve a video classification problem. While looking for solutions, I only found solutions that transform this problem into a series of simpler image classification tasks. However, this method has a downside: we ignore the temporal relationship between the frames.

So, how can I perform video classification, with a CNN, by taking into account the temporal relationships between frames?

Comment: I edited this post to simplify and clarify it, and to make it more consistent with the answer that you accepted. Please, make sure that I did not change the meaning of it. If I did, you can just edit your post again and clarify what you're asking. If not, please, flag this comment for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at spatio-temporal CNNs which extend the image-based CNN in 2D to 3D to handle time.  These are commonly used to detect or classify action in a video.  People have used them to identify specific actions in various sports such as kicking a soccer ball, throwing a baseball or dribbling a basketball.  They have been used to identify fire, smoke, deep fakes, and violence in videos.  Below are some articles to help get started.

- [Introduction to Video Classification, by Connor Shorten](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-video-classification-6c6acbc57356)
- [Are you ready for a Video Classification Challenge? Preparation Guide for Video Classification, by Neha Goel](https://towardsdatascience.com/are-you-ready-for-a-video-classification-challenge-d044e3b202b6)
- [MiCT-Net for Human Action Recognition in Videos, by Florent Mahoudeau](https://towardsdatascience.com/mict-net-for-human-action-recognition-in-videos-3a18e4f97342)

Source code:

- [Video Classification](https://github.com/HHTseng/video-classification)
- [Video Classification Using 3D ResNet](https://github.com/kenshohara/video-classification-3d-cnn-pytorch)